# How do I make the changes I made to my .bashrc file persist across my terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

So I have found myself recently cd'ing through the same files over and over again, so I thought I'd add an alias in my .bashrc file to do it for me. It works, but only when after I enter the command . ~/.bashrc or exec bash. Is there a way to make sure that whenever I start up my terminal it just remembers the alias I made?

Thank you!

Comment: So are you sure you use `bash` in your terminal?

Comment: Pretty sure. It says bash in the top center. Im on OSX btw.

Comment: log out and back in. You have to manually load the .bashrc in the session where you make the changes, but the next session should pick them up.

Comment: How do I do that? So far Ive used . ~/.bashrc, quit the window, then quit the terminal, then reopen it.

Comment: Just fixed it. I just had the terminal run bash on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened preferences and just had it run 'bash' on startup.